# Laravel - React , Image Upload Issue when updating the data

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I have a problem when i try to update my merchandise data. the problem is when i try to input the image field causing all the $request data which i inputed become null `[] // app/Http/Controllers/Merchandise/MerchandiseController.php:122` but when i input all the data except the image file the data other than image updated properly.

this is my code

```
 import React, { useEffect,useState } from 'react';
 import AuthenticatedLayout from '@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout';
 import InputError from '@/Components/InputError';
 import InputLabel from '@/Components/InputLabel';
 import NumberInput from '@/Components/NumberInput';
 import DateInput from '@/Components/DateInput';
 import PrimaryButton from '@/Components/PrimaryButton';
 import SelectBoxEditId from '@/Components/SelectBoxEditId';
 import Flash from '@/Components/Flash';
 import TextInput from '@/Components/TextInput';
 import { useForm , usePage } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react';

 export default function EditMerchandise (props){
  const {merchandise} = usePage().props
  const { data, setData, put, processing, errors, reset } = useForm({
    name: merchandise.name || '',
    description: merchandise.description || '',
    merchandise_category_id: merchandise.merchandise_category_id || 0,
    price: merchandise.price || 0,
    date: merchandise.date || '',
    stock: merchandise.stock || 0,
    image: null,
    
});

const onHandleChange = (event) => {
    setData(event.target.name, event.target.type === 'checkbox' ? event.target.checked : event.target.value);
};

const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    put(route('merchandise.update',merchandise.id));
};



return (
    <AuthenticatedLayout auth={props.auth} errors={props.errors}>
    <div className="w-full lg:max-w-6xl mt-6 px-6 py-4 bg-white shadow-md overflow-hidden sm:rounded-lg">        
        { props.flash.message !== null ? <Flash message = {props.flash.message}/> : <div></div>}    
        <form onSubmit={submit}>
            <div>
                <InputLabel forInput="name" value="Name" />

                <TextInput
                    type="text"
                    name="name"
                    value={data.name}
                    className="m-2 input input-bordered w-full"
                    handleChange={onHandleChange}
         
                />
                <InputError message={errors.name} className="mt-2" />

                <InputLabel forInput="category" value="Category"/>   
                <SelectBoxEditId className
                    name="merchandise_category_id"
                    value={data.merchandise_category_id}
                    data={props.merchandiseMaster}
                    selected={merchandise.merchandise_master.name}
                    id={parseInt(merchandise.merchandise_master.id)}
                    handleChange={onHandleChange}       
                />
                <InputError message={errors.merchandise_category_id} className="mt-2" />

                <InputLabel forInput="price" value="Price" />
                <NumberInput 
                    type="number"
                    name="price"
                    value={data.price}
                    className="m-2 input input-bordered w-full"
                    handleChange={onHandleChange}

                />
                <InputError message={errors.price} className="mt-2" />

                <InputLabel forInput="name" value="Description" />
                <TextInput 
                    type="text"
                    name="description"
                    value={data.description}
                    className="m-2 input input-bordered w-full"
                    handleChange={onHandleChange}

                />
                <InputError message={errors.description} className="mt-2" />

                <InputLabel forInput="date" value="Date" />
                <DateInput 
                    type="date"
                    name="date"
                    value={data.date}
                    className="m-2 input input-bordered w-full"
                    handleChange={onHandleChange}

                />
                <InputError message={errors.date} className="mt-2" />

                <InputLabel forInput="stock" value="Stock" />
                <NumberInput
                    type="number"
                    name="stock"
                    value={data.stock}
                    className="m-2 input input-bordered w-full"
                    handleChange={onHandleChange}
         
                />
                <InputError message={errors.stock} className="mt-2" />

                //this is the image field
                <InputLabel forInput="Image" value="Image" />
                <div className="flex flex-col items-start">
                    <input
                        type="file"
                        name="image"
                        className={
                            `file-input file-input-bordered file-input-accent w-full max-w-xs` 
                        }
                        onChange={(e) => setData("image", e.target.files[0])}
                    />
                </div>
                <InputError message={errors.image} className="mt-2" />



         
                <PrimaryButton className="" >
                    Submit
                </PrimaryButton>


            </div>

        </form>
    </div>

    </AuthenticatedLayout>
    
)
```

}

and this is my controller

```
 public function update(Request $request ,Merchandise $merchandise)
{
    $request->validate([
        'stock' => 'required|integer',
        'merchandise_category_id' => 'required|integer',
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:merchandises,name,'.$request->id,
        'price' => 'required|integer',
        'description' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'date' => 'required|date'         
        
    ]);
 
    if($request->file('image')){
        //delete old file
        Storage::disk('local')->delete('public/image/'.basename($image->img));
        //add new file
        $images = $request->file('image');
        $images->storeAs('public/image', $images->hashName());

        $image = Merchandise::where('id', $request->id)->update([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'price' => $request->price,
            'merchandise_category_id' => $request->merchandise_category_id,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'date' => $request->date,
            'stock' => $request->stock,
            'image' => $image->hashName(),
            'user_id' => auth()->guard('web')->user()->id
          
        ]);


        if($update){
            return to_route('merchandise')->with('message', 'Data Nerchandise BERHASIL diUpdate');
        }

        return to_route('merchandise')->with('message', 'Data Nerchandise GAGAL diUpdate');

    }

    //if no image
    $update = Merchandise::where('id', $request->id)->update([
     
        'name' => $request->name,
        'price' => $request->price,
        'merchandise_category_id' => $request->merchandise_category_id,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'date' => $request->date,
        'stock' => $request->stock,
        'user_id' => auth()->guard('web')->user()->id
      
    ]);


    if($update){
        return to_route('merchandise')->with('message', 'Data Nerchandise BERHASIL diUpdate');
    }

    return to_route('merchandise')->with('message', 'Data Nerchandise GAGAL diUpdate');
    
}
```

im really confused about the problem i really dont have any idea how to solve this problems

please help me thankyou in advance

Answer (score 1):

i have the same problem.

and i solve the problem with changing the function submit from this :

```
const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    put(route('merchandise.update',merchandise.id));
};
```

to this :

```
import { router } from '@inertiajs/react';

const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    router.post(route('merchandise.update',merchandise.id), {
    ...data,
    _method: 'put',
    forceFormData: true,
});
};
```

and you change 'put' from :

```
const { data, setData, put, processing, errors, reset } = useForm({.....});
```

to this :

```
const { data, setData, processing, errors, reset } = useForm({.....});
```